# Adobe ExtendScript Toolkit Finding an Object’s Properties and Methods

Tags: javascript, adobe, extendscript

I'm new to Adobe Scripting, and Javascripting in general, and I'm reading the guide "ADOBE INTRODUCTION TO SCRIPTING" and the "JAVASCRIPT TOOLS GUIDE". But something is bugging me.

In the first one it says that to find the properties and methods of a Object I have to use the Model Object View, but this doesn't exist for the After Effects and Premiere(the Applications I'm mostly working with). I've been using reflect.properties/methods to get this info, but that's gets very time-consuming when I need to get methods/properties of many Objects.

My question is: How can I effectively get this info? Is there any online resource with this kind of info? The PDF's are okay, but its not the fastest way to find many properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe After Effects comes with [a scripting guide](http://blogs.adobe.com/aftereffects/files/2012/06/After-Effects-CS6-Scripting-Guide.pdf?file=2012/06/After-Effects-CS6-Scripting-Guide.pdf) outlining pretty much all properties and methods for the objects it has.  The problem is that Adobe has not had an opportunity to create a scripting guide for the latest versions of AE.  But there are some resources available to you for that as well.  Like [the blog posts made by the QE team for AE](http://blogs.adobe.com/aftereffects/2014/03/scripting-changes-in-after-effects-cc-12-0-12-2.html).

If you use the ExtendScript Toolkit (ESTK) IDE you'll also have access to a "data browser" panel that will outline the methods and properties available to you as you debug.  When I need to inspect any object while developing scripts for AE, I'll place a breakpoint in the ESTK IDE and then open up my data browser to see everything available to scripting.  Hope that helps!

Comment: The debug is quite helpfull with things that you can change on the go, but I'm messing with the addProperty(), and it's quite annoying trying to figure out what I can add or not. I'm spending more timing googling how to use each method/propertie than actually coding.